# Unable to install ggm package un R language

Tags: r

I'm currently operating in macOS with the R version of 3.6.3.

When I tried to install the package ggm, a warning occurred as follows.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘graph’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘igraph’
```

Then when it completed installing, it seemed not to work either:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/igraph’
ERROR: dependencies ‘igraph’, ‘graph’ are not available for package ‘ggm’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/ggm’
```

What is happening? I have searched for this error and didn't find anything that helps. Please help me. I'll be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

To install the package `graph` you need to install the latest version of Bioconductor (i.e. package called `BioManager`).

Then you install the package `graph` and then simply run the installation for the `ggm` package.

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("graph")

install.packages("ggm")
library(ggm)
```

The package is then loaded into your R enviroment.